# Passport won't serialize the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have made the `serializeUser` and `deserializerUser` functions, yet it doesn't serialize the data. I have made sure the order of `app.use(session)` and `app.use(passport.initialize())` is correct too. Please help!

**Passport.js**

```js
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require('../src/models/users');

const verifyCallback = (req, email, password, done) => {
    let isValid = false;
    // console.log(email, password);
    User.findOne({ email: email }).exec()
        .then(user => {
            if (user) {
                if (user.password == password) {
                    console.log('valid ');
                    return done(null, user, {message: true})
                } else {
                    console.log(' not valid');
                    return done(null, false, {message: false});
                }
            } else {
                console.log('verifycallback !user');
                return done(null, false, {message: false})
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);

        });
}

const strategy = new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password', passReqToCallback: true}, verifyCallback);

passport.use(strategy);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    try {
        console.log(user.id);
        done(null, user.id);
    } catch (e)
    {
        console.log(`serialize error ${e}`)
    }

})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    console.log(`deserializing ${id}`);
    User.findById(id).then((foundUser) => { // Use a different parameter name here
        done(null, foundUser);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(`deserialize err ${err}`);
        done(err);
    });
});
```

**server.js**

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose')

const express=require("express")
const db=require('./mongo')
const app=express()
const cors=require('cors')
const dotenv=require('dotenv');
const passport = require('passport');
const session=require('express-session')
const User = require('../src/models/users');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

require('../config/passport');

dotenv.config();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(cors())

app.use(session({
    secret: 'your-secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: MongoStore.create({mongoUrl: process.env.URL, collectionName: 'sessions'}),
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000*60*60*24 // 1 day
    }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/' ,async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(`$red.user: ${req.user}`); // even req.user.id doesn't work
})
```

I keep getting

```
valid 
<user.id> from serialize function, but it's not serialzing it in the session
serialized
$red.user: undefined
```

as the output

**even req.user.id doesn't work**

Comment: the very first problem I saw in your code was that you didn't use await key work before User.findOne and additionally, I recommend you to evaluate finding inside a const so you can handle the value more efficiently than then().catch and I mean something like this    const user = User.findOne()....